# Changing keys after loading json file dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Okay, so I am having this issue with JSON, keys, and strings. I'm using a JSON dump in python to save my game dictionaries and it does work. The issue is when I load the dictionaries the game I'm making uses int values as keys in the world directory but JSON stores keys as strings. Here's a random generation I did.

```
worldmap = {
   'Regions': {
1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Forest Path', 3: 'Baronbell', 4: 'Old Path', 5: 'Cariva', 6: 'Prairie Path'},

   'Zelbridge': {1: 'Field', 2: 'Prairie Path', 3: 'School', 4: 'Mountain Path', 5: 'Graveyard',
      6: 'Old Path', 7: 'Blacksmith', 8: 'Forest Path', 9: 'Doctor', 0: 'Zelbridge'},

   'Forest Path': {1: 'Trees', 2: 'Bushes', 3: 'Path', 4: 'Cariva', 5: 'Path',
      6: 'Baronbell', 7: 'Path', 8: 'Zelbridge', 9: 'Path', 0: 'Forest Path'}, 

   'Baronbell': {1: 'House', 2: 'Mountain Path', 3: 'Graveyard', 4: 'Old Path', 5: 'Field',
      6: 'Forest Path', 7: 'Church', 8: 'Prairie Path', 9: 'Shop', 0: 'Baronbell'},

   'Old Path': {1: 'Path', 2: 'Trees', 3: 'Bushes', 4: 'Cariva', 5: 'Path', 
     6: 'Zelbridge', 7: 'Trees', 8: 'Baronbell', 9: 'Trees', 0: 'Old Path'}, 

   'Cariva': {1: 'Cellar', 2: 'Old Path', 3: 'Graveyard', 4: 'Mountain Path', 5: 'Town Hall', 
     6: 'Prairie Path', 7: 'School', 8: 'Forest Path', 9: 'Blacksmith', 0: 'Cariva'}, 

   'Prairie Path': {1: 'Bushes', 2: 'Path', 3: 'Path', 4: 'Zelbridge', 5: 'Trees', 
     6: 'Cariva', 7: 'Trees', 8: 'Baronbell', 9: 'Path', 0: 'Prairie Path'}
}
```

So when I use the load function I get key errors due to the int's being converted to strings. I attempted a for loop to iterate over the keys and change them back but I get this error about the dictionary changing. Here's an example of me trying to load a different (and also random) world. Its set to print after each loop showing that it works

```
What was your hero's name? #Input hero name
Loading...
{'2': 'Prairie Path', '3': 'Cariva', '4': 'Old Path', '5': 'Baronbell', '6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge'} #Region number 1 no longer string

{'3': 'Cariva', '4': 'Old Path', '5': 'Baronbell', '6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Prairie Path'} #Region numbers 1 and 2 no longer string

{'4': 'Old Path', '5': 'Baronbell', '6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Prairie Path', 3: 'Cariva'} #ect

{'5': 'Baronbell', '6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Prairie Path', 3: 'Cariva', 4: 'Old Path'} #ect

{'6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Prairie Path', 3: 'Cariva', 4: 'Old Path', 5: 'Baronbell'} # Region numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 no longer string

{'6': 'Mountain Path', 1: 'Zelbridge', 2: 'Prairie Path', 3: 'Cariva', 5: 'Baronbell'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/crazy/PycharmProjects/rpg/main.py", line 581, in load
    for key in worldmap["Regions"]:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with it but sadly I'll also have to do this for each location within a region. Any and all help is appreciated, as I've looked all over SO and google but to no avail.

````
        with open(world_file) as infile:
            worldmap = json.load(infile)
            copy = worldmap.copy()
            regions = worldmap["Regions"]
            locations = copy.pop("Regions")
            for key in worldmap["Regions"]:
                value = worldmap["Regions"][key]
                new_key = int(key)
                worldmap["Regions"].update({new_key: value})
                worldmap ["Regions"].pop(key)
                print(str(worldmap["Regions"]) + "\n")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use For loop this way and update the key in loop itself:

```
mydict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print("index: {}, key: {}, value: {}".format(index, key, value))
    mydict[index] = mydict.pop(key)
```

Or use can use List to force a copy of the keys to be made:

```
mydict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
for index, key in enumerate(list(mydict)):
    mydict[index] = mydict.pop(key)
 
 # which will give output like:
 # ---------------------------
 # {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
```